# RPC error "transport is closing" during peer channel fetch

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a problem with BYFN in Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.3.

I ran `byfn.sh generate` and `byfn.sh up` without problems

I need to fetch a block. When I run this command:

`peer channel fetch newest mychannel.block -c mychannel --orderer orderer.example.com:7050`

from docker cli bash,  I get the following error:

> error receiving: rpc error code = unavailable desc = transport is closing

How to fix this?

Comment: I think TLS is enabled in the network, you have to provide cafile path and tls flag in the command. Try this command : "peer channel fetch newest mychannel.block --channelID mychannel --orderer orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem"

Comment: It works ok. Thank you Sneha.